# Why can't I specify a minimum frequency for a CountVectorizer when I supply a custom vocabulary in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I understand that it is possible to specify a minimum frequency when it comes to creating a count vectorizer within the Scikit-learn package in Python.  However, I'm wondering if this is only the case if you do not provide an a-priori dictionary?  When I supply my own custom vocabulary (a list), this parameter appears to not work.

To figure this out, I reread the documentation for the `min_df` argument:

```
Parameters :

min_df : float in range [0.0, 1.0] or int, optional, 1 by default

    When building the vocabulary, ignore terms that have a term frequency strictly lower than the given threshold.  

    This value is also called cut-off in the literature.   

    If float, the parameter represents a proportion of documents, integer absolute counts. This parameter is ignored if vocabulary is not None.
```

In my case, I supplied to my CountVectorizer a custom vocabulary that is made up of my own terms that I obtained previously.

```
cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=my_own_terms, min_df=3)
X = cv.fit_transform(a_big_corpus)
```

As I look at the output, I'm getting all sorts of terms that appear once, twice, etc.

Has anyone had this occur in their work, and if so, is there a possible solution?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By supplying the set of vocabulary, it means that you want *exactly* that set of vocabulary. Anything else does not matter, even if a term only appear once or does not appear at all in the text to be transformed. Otherwise, it contradicts with your implied intention (by supplying the `vocabulary` parameter) that you want *exactly* that set of vocabulary. Thus, it seems reasonable that the `min_df` constraint should be ignored, which is the case according to the documentation.

Based on your follow up comment, it seems that what you want is:

> I want 'exactly' those items in my vocabulary, but if a word occurs occurs only once, then I don't want it.

which basically means that you want the terms within your pre-extracted set of vocabulary which appear frequently enough. In other words, you actually don't really want exactly those vocabulary. I would probably do it like this:

1. Fit from scratch a brand new `CounterVectorizer` on your data.
2. Take the intersection between the vocabulary of the newly fitted vectorizer above with your a-priori set of vocabulary.
3. Construct the actual `CountVectorizer` which does the real transform using the vocabulary intersected in step 2.

Your approach directly jumps to step 3, which is why the vectorizer does not work as you have expected.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the point of using `vocabulary` is to say that you want exactly those items in your vocabulary, so `min_df` isn't applicable.  If you still want a minimum frequency, you'll have to do the vectorizing, see which ones are too small, and then remove them from your custom vocabulary and re-vectorize.  (As far as I can see, there's no way to remove items from the vocabulary of an existing CountVectorizer.)

Comment: Is that just me, or doesn't it seem a little silly?  Of course I want 'exactly' those items in my vocabulary, but if a word occurs occurs only once, then I don't want it.  Seems to me pretty reasonable.  Regardless of my personal opinion, thanks for the response and explanation.

Comment: @MattO'Brien Either you want it and you specify it, or you don't want it and don't specify it. It would be surprising if the library post-processed an explicitly specified vocabulary.